# Can't type less than or greater than

Tags: keyboard

I have a Hama Key4All X300 wireless keyboard that functions well except for the fact that I can't type the less than and greater than signs with it. The <kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd> keys themselves work, and so does shift, but when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> absolutely nothing happens. I have tried the Keyboard Layout Creater 1.4 program and remapped <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to the less than sign but than still doesn't solve the problem. The operating system is Windows 10 Pro x64. I don't know what to do anymore. Please help!

Comment: A little update:I mapped Del to , so now I can type <. Trying to figure out what to do with the other one.

Comment: And I eventually mapped them to F10 and F11. Still I'd much rather use the proper keys so let me know if you have any ideas on what might be causing this.